# Show rows with zero value

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following query to display the number of persons based on gender:

```
 SELECT gender, 
    count( * ) AS count
 FROM persons
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT count( * ) AS total 
                FROM persons) x
 GROUP BY 1
 ORDER BY gender DESC
```

With as result:

```
Male    | 5
```

How to also also display rows with zero value, e.g.:

```
Male    | 5
Female  | 0
```

Comment: is `gender` = 1 for male and 0 for female?

Comment: What is the output for SELECT gender, 
    count( * ) AS count
    FROM persons
    GROUP BY 1
    ORDER BY gender DESC

Comment: Do you have a table with all genders in it?

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` ? Is this question for MySQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simpler solution to find out the count of male/female

```
SELECT  
    SUM(gender='Male' ) AS `Male`,
    SUM(gender='Female' ) AS `Female`
 FROM persons
 GROUP BY gender
```

This will produce output like

```
Male  Female
5       0
```

Or to show row wise you can use union

```
SELECT 'Male' AS gender,COUNT(*) `count` FROM persons WHERE gender='Male'
UNION
SELECT 'Female' AS gender,COUNT(*) `count` FROM persons WHERE gender='Female'
```

This will output as

```
gender count

Male   5
Female 0
```

Comment: +1 because that'll certainly work (well if that's what's in the field anyway). I was hoping the OP had a table for genders.

Comment: ?? `SUM(gender='Female') AS Female`  ?? do you have a typo ?

Comment: @OllieJones Thanks for the correction that was a typo

Comment: This should be **UNION ALL**. It makes no sense to have the dbms look out for duplicates where there can be none.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner if you see the query there is no chance for having duplicate records reason is i have used count with out group by so each query will produce one row which is definitely different from the other one because ('Male' AS gender ,'Female' AS gender) is different so i would say there is no need to be curious for having duplicates hope it will give you clear picture

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid: This is what I am saying. You should only use UNION instead of UNION ALL when you want to remove duplicates. As there can be no duplicates, there is no reason to use UNION. Use UNION ALL instead.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if what you're looking for is actually something as quick as gender, you can always `UNION ALL` it.

```
SELECT [Gender], COUNT(*) [Total] FROM [Persons] WHERE [Gender] = 'Male' GROUP BY [Gender]

UNION ALL

SELECT [Gender], COUNT(*) [Total] FROM [Persons] WHERE [Gender] = 'Female' GROUP BY [Gender]
```

Comment: This should be **UNION ALL**. It makes no sense to have the dbms look out for duplicates where there can be none.